How to force Visual Studio to restore .esproj when package.lock.json is present
I have a .esproj which is used to restore npm packages in Visual Studio.
However it will only restore when there is no package-lock.json. However since node_modules is in .gitignore, developers who checkout the repo will have a package-lock.json, but no modules downloaded yet.
So how can I force Visual Studio to restore npm packages when package-lock.json is present?
Using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.10.4

I used a hash file to detect when it changed:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.89-alpha">  
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ShouldRunNpmInstall>false</ShouldRunNpmInstall>
        <ShouldRunNpmBuildScript>false</ShouldRunNpmBuildScript>
        
        <!-- Define the paths for package-lock.json and the hash file -->
        <PackageLockFile>$(ProjectDir)package-lock.json</PackageLockFile>
        <PackageLockHashFile>$(ProjectDir)package-lock.hash</PackageLockHashFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="CheckNpmPackages" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <!-- Calculate the file hash using GetFileHash -->
        <GetFileHash Files="$(PackageLockFile)" Algorithm="SHA256">
            <Output TaskParameter="Hash" PropertyName="CurrentHash" />
        </GetFileHash>

        <!-- Read previous hash from file, only if it exists -->
        <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(PackageLockHashFile)" Condition="Exists('$(PackageLockHashFile)')">
            <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="PreviousHash" />
        </ReadLinesFromFile>

        <!-- Run npm ci if the hash has changed -->
        <Exec Command="npm ci --no-audit" Condition="$(CurrentHash) != $(PreviousHash)" />

        <!-- Save the current hash to the file -->
        <WriteLinesToFile File="$(PackageLockHashFile)" Lines="$(CurrentHash)" Overwrite="true" />
    </Target>
</Project>

